# Tool for graphing dependencies in an Ant build file and its imports

Tags: ant, visualization, diagram, build.xml

What tool can take an Ant build file as input and display a graph of all the target dependencies? It should consider imports as well.

I tried vizant, but it does not read imported files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Grand](https://ant-grand.github.io/Grand/grand.html)** might be more complete than VizAnt.

See [this blog](http://www.rekk.de/bloggy/2008/visualizing-default-ant-task-dependencies-for-netbeans-build-implxml/) post as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some, see the [Ant external tools page](http://ant.apache.org/external.html).  From there:

- [Grand](https://ant-grand.github.io/Grand/grand.html)
- [Nurflugel](http://www.nurflugel.com/webstart/AntScriptVisualizer/)

Answer (score 1):

yworks Ant Explorer is (was) great, there are several versions , standalone and eclipse plugin.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184562/130683) for download link of standalone version and intellij plugin, use searchengine to find eclipse plugin.