# Tool for visualizing Ant build.xml files' dependencies

Tags: java, ant, visualization, diagram, build.xml

I'm taking over a couple of projects with fairly complex build.xml files. Which tool do you recommend to help me visualize all the files' dependencies?

I've found [ant2dot.xsl](http://ant2dot.sourceforge.net/) and [Vizant](http://vizant.sourceforge.net/). I just wanted to see what other options are out there and what people prefer.

Comment: I just found this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134918/ant-check-dependcies) suggesting Grand. Is this what everyone else preferes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like Grand best of the three because it handles imported build files the best.  Since I rely heavily on imports, this is critical.

In 2007, I had written an [article comparing the three](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200711/ant_dependency_graph.html) along with an example of the output of each.  I just checked and not have the libraries have change significantly in that time so the analysis still holds.

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak things a little to get it to run but I now have a pretty useful diagram thanks to Grand.