# yWorks Ant Explorer

Tags: ant

I want to know which file has the main function in the yWorks_Ant_Explorer.jar. I am unable to start the jar file.
It gives me error:
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
yWorks_Ant_Explorer_1692.jar

I have checked in the manifest file, there is no main class specified. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Think you got the plugin version for IntelliJ. You need the standalone version, which is officially not around anymore. Searched a bit and found a [Blog entry](http://myblog.chaiware.org/2009/02/ant-explorer-graphical-ant-build-tool.html) which has a working [download link for the standalone version of antexplorer](http://blogstorage.chaiware.org/files-1/Antexplorer.V1.03.zip).